Getting Error 2771 on a Web Browser Object in MS Access
I'm trying to create and run the Google OAuth2 from an MS-Access 2016 Application. I realize this is old code but it's the most readable OAuth2 VBA code to get an authorization code that I've found in hours of looking.However, it throws two errors.  Both are on the web browser object from these two lines of code:
  Call Me.WebBrowser1.Object.Navigate2("about:blank", navNoReadFromCache) /\* Found in **Private Sub Form_Load()** \*/

  Call Me.WebBrowser1.Object.Document.Write(resTxt.responseText) /\*Found in **Private Sub startOauth2()** \*/

The resTXT.responseText is being sent back, I can see it in debug.
I get the second error by commenting out the first Call.  The error in the same for both calls:
Error 2771:  The bound or unbound object frame you tried to edit does not contain an OLE object.
I'm trying to replace my CDO sendmail code with OAuth2 code.
